# Find out range for every field in a column

Tags: indexing, awk, range, tcl

I have a column that looks like this:

```
A 1
B 3
C 5
D 4
E 7
F 1
G 1
H 3
```

For every filed in column#2, I want to calculate the range (max-min) of 3 field radius up and down.

```
A range(1 3 5 4)
B range(1 3 5 4 7)
C range(1 3 5 4 7 1)
D range(1 3 5 4 7 1 1)
E range(  3 5 4 7 1 1 3)
F range(    5 4 7 1 1 3)
G range(      4 7 1 1 3)
H range(        7 1 1 3)
```

How can do this in awk?

I could do the same in perl using:

```
my $set_size = @values;
for ( my $i = 0 ; $i < $set_size ; $i++ ) {
    my $min = $i - 4;
    if ( $min < 0 ) { $min = 0; }
    my $max = $i + 4;
    if ( $max > ( $set_size - 1 ) ) { $max = $set_size - 1; }
    my $min_val = $values[$min];
    my $max_val = $values[$min];
    for ( my $j = $min ; $j <= $max ; $j++ ) {
        if ( $values[$j] <= $min_val ) { $min_val = $values[$j]; }
        if ( $values[$j] >= $max_val ) { $max_val = $values[$j]; }
    }
    my $range = $max_val - $min_val;
    printf "$points[$i] %.15f\n", $range;
}
```

Comment: How can it be done not in awk? Even if you don't know the exact syntax of a particular tool you want to use at least provide the pseudo-code for the algorithm you want to employ so you can show some kind of attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Comment: I could do the same in perl using: my $set_size = @values;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $set_size; $i++) {
 my $min = $i - 4;
 if ($min < 0) {
  $min = 0;
 }
 my $max = $i + 4;
 if ($max > ($set_size-1)) {
  $max = $set_size - 1;
 }

 my $min_val = $values[$min];
 my $max_val = $values[$min];
 for (my $j = $min; $j <= $max; $j++) {
  if ($values[$j] <= $min_val) {
    $min_val = $values[$j];
  }
  if ($values[$j] >= $max_val) {
    $max_val = $values[$j];
  }
 }
 my $range = $max_val - $min_val;
 printf "$points[$i] %.15f\n", $range;
}

Comment: I ran the code in your comment through the perl formatter at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_perl_formatter.htm and put it in the question for you. idk what exactly it means, of course, but maybe someone else will. If you know how to do it in perl, though, why do you want to do it in awk? And why have you tagged the question with `tcl`?

Comment: That perl doesn't print out your sample output. (It can also be rewritten to be a fraction of the length and be more clear...)

Answer (score 0):

idk exactly what `I want to calculate the range (max-min) of 3 field radius up and down.` means but to get the output you posted from the input you posted would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    keys[NR] = $1
    values[NR] = $2
}
END {
    range = 3
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        min = ( (i - range) >= 1  ? i - range : 1  )
        max = ( (i + range) <= NR ? i + range : NR )
        printf "%s range(", keys[i]
        for (j=min; j<=max; j++) {
            printf "%s%s", values[j], (j<max ? " " : ")\n")
        }
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A range(1 3 5 4)
B range(1 3 5 4 7)
C range(1 3 5 4 7 1)
D range(1 3 5 4 7 1 1)
E range(3 5 4 7 1 1 3)
F range(5 4 7 1 1 3)
G range(4 7 1 1 3)
H range(7 1 1 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample perl doesn't print out your sample output, it seems to do something different... so here's how I'd do it in perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use List::Util qw/min max/;

my (@col1, @col2);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($v1, $v2) = split;
    push @col1, $v1;
    push @col2, $v2;
}

my @prefix;
for my $i (0 .. $#col1) {
    my @range = @col2[max($i - 3, 0) .. min($i + 3, $#col2)];
    push @prefix, ' ' if $i > 3;
    unshift @range, @prefix;
    say "$col1[$i] range(@range)"
}
```

running it:

```
$ perl range.pl input.txt
A range(1 3 5 4)
B range(1 3 5 4 7)
C range(1 3 5 4 7 1)
D range(1 3 5 4 7 1 1)
E range(  3 5 4 7 1 1 3)
F range(    5 4 7 1 1 3)
G range(      4 7 1 1 3)
H range(        7 1 1 3)
```

The formatting will break if any of the numbers are greater than 9, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl):

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

lassign $argv file size

set fh [open $file r]
# assume exactly 2 space-separated words per line
set data [dict create {*}[split [read -nonewline $fh]]]
close $fh

set len [dict size $data]
set values [dict values $data]
set i 0

dict for {key _} $data {
    set first [expr {max($i - $size, 0)}]
    set last  [expr {min($i + $size, $len)}]
    puts [format "%s range(%s%s)" \
        $key \
        [string repeat "  " $first] \
        [lrange $values $first $last] \
    ]
    incr i
}
```

outputs

```
A range(1 3 5 4)
B range(1 3 5 4 7)
C range(1 3 5 4 7 1)
D range(1 3 5 4 7 1 1)
E range(  3 5 4 7 1 1 3)
F range(    5 4 7 1 1 3)
G range(      4 7 1 1 3)
H range(        7 1 1 3)
```

Answer (score -5):

[TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) at the shell prompt:

```
bash$ txr -c '@(collect)
@label @num
@(end)
@(bind rng @[window-map 3 nil (opip list (remq nil) (mapcar toint)) num])
@(output)
@  (repeat)
@label range(@rng) -> @(find-min rng)..@(find-max rng) 
@  (end)
@(end)' 
A 1
B 3
C 5
D 4
E 7
F 1
G 1
H 3
[Ctrl-D][Enter]
A range(1 3 5 4) -> 1..5 
B range(1 3 5 4 7) -> 1..7 
C range(1 3 5 4 7 1) -> 1..7 
D range(1 3 5 4 7 1 1) -> 1..7 
E range(3 5 4 7 1 1 3) -> 1..7 
F range(5 4 7 1 1 3) -> 1..7 
G range(4 7 1 1 3) -> 1..7 
H range(7 1 1 3) -> 1..7
```

Comment: Why are you posting a solution in a language that the user has not indicated that they want to use?

Comment: @DonalFellows I promote the language as its author.